# React - conditional rendering of Javascript and JSX, conditional wrapper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to conditionally render several shared components but am getting an error:

> **Line 182:9:**  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw
>   an expression  no-unused-expressions

The below works perfectly without the `<Conditional />` wrapper component. However, a new client requirement is that a higher level condition be placed on all components, before reaching the component-specific if-else statement. I wanted to create a wrapper component `<Conditional />` instead of inflating the existing if-else statements with more conditions or duplicating code.

To render this appropriately, I wrapped the if-else statements with an anonymous arrow function. But the error remains!

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
...
return (
    <Grid container>
      {enhancedSections.map((section, index) => {
        <Conditional    // this is line 182
          path={section.conditional ? section.conditional.param_name : null }
          section={section}
        >
          {() => {
            if (   // these series of if-else statements renders perfectly without the <Conditional/> wrapper
              section.style == "single_select" &&
              section.section_display_name == selectedSection
            ) {
                return (
                  <SingleSelect
                    key={section.definition.display_name}
                    displayName={section.definition.display_name}
                    description={
                      section.definition.description
                        ? section.definition.description
                        : null
                    }
                    path={{ id: id, field: `${section.field}` }}
                  />
                );
              } else if (
                section.style == "boolean" &&
                section.section_display_name == selectedSection
              ) {
                return (
                  <Boolean
                    key={section.definition.display_name}
                    displayName={section.definition.display_name}
                    description={section.definition.description}
                    path={{ id: id, field: `${section.field}` }}
                  />
                );
              } else if (
                ...   // more conditional cmps here 
              )
          }}
        </Conditional>
      })
     }
    </Grid>
  );
```

The purpose of `<Conditional/>` is to only render its `props.children` if `shouldRender()` returns `true`.

```js
const Conditional = props => {

  const shouldRender = path => {
    if(!props.path){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }

  return (
    shouldRender() ? props.children : null
  );
}

export default Conditional;
```

Comment: Instead of `return true` etc, just `return !props.path` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

The `children` provided to `Conditional` is a `function`. To render **children as a function**(render props) you should execute it like this

```
shouldRender() ? props.children() : null
```

Answer (score 1):

`children` is a function, you just need to invoke `children`.

An example: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-cloud-sql0d

EDIT:
forgot to mention one more thing - in your "shouldRender" function, you specified path but you never use it, because it's in your props, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your *enhancedSections.map* does not actually return anything.

```
return (
    <Grid container>
      {enhancedSections.map((section, index) => (
        <Conditional    // this is line 182
          path={section.conditional ? section.conditional.param_name : null }
          section={section}
        >
          {() => {
            if (   // these series of if-else statements renders perfectly without the <Conditional/> wrapper
              section.style == "single_select" &&
              section.section_display_name == selectedSection
            ) {
                return (
                  <SingleSelect
                    key={section.definition.display_name}
                    displayName={section.definition.display_name}
                    description={
                      section.definition.description
                        ? section.definition.description
                        : null
                    }
                    path={{ id: id, field: `${section.field}` }}
                  />
                );
              } else if (
                section.style == "boolean" &&
                section.section_display_name == selectedSection
              ) {
                return (
                  <Boolean
                    key={section.definition.display_name}
                    displayName={section.definition.display_name}
                    description={section.definition.description}
                    path={{ id: id, field: `${section.field}` }}
                  />
                );
              } else if (
                ...   // more conditional cmps here 
              )
          }}
        </Conditional>
      ))
     }
    </Grid>
  );
```

This way the enhancedSections.map function will return the component for every enhanced section and the render should be successful.

The reason it was working before adding the *Conditional* component was because each if-else statement returned a component and that component was used by the map function.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I added examples that recreate your behavior in codesandbox:

[Failing code (without a return statement)](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-leftpad-5bzqu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[Working examples (when returning the element)](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-shape-uy23u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)